# Como inverter uma image dentro de uma @keyframe?

Tags: css

Bom eu estou a usar esta `@keyframe`, mas após o descer para a direita eu gostaria que a imagem fosse invertida, este código faz a inversão como eu quero:

```
img {
//      -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
//      -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
//      -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
//      transform: scaleX(-1);
//      filter: FlipH;
//      -ms-filter: "FlipH";
//    }
```

E esta e a minha `@keyframe`:

```
@keyframes move {
  0%   { top: 750px; left: 0px; transform: translate(0, 0); } //posição inicial
  10%  { top: 750px; left: 100%; transform: translate(-135%, 0) } //vai para a direita
  15%  { top: 1100px; left: 100%; transform: translate(-135%, -50%) } //desce do lado direito
  25%  { top: 1100px; left: 0px; transform: translate(35%, -50%) } //vai para a esquerda
  30%  { top: 1500px; left: 0px; transform: translate(35%, -120%) } //desce do lado esquerdo
  40%  { top: 1500px; left: 100%; transform: translate(-120%, -120%) } //vai para a direita
  45%  { top: 1500px; left: 100%; transform: translate(-120%, -50%) } //desce do lado direito
  55%  { top: 1500px; left: 0px; transform: translate(35%, -50%) } //vai para a esquerda
  60%  { top: 1910px; left: 0px; transform: translate(35%, -120%) } //desce do lado esquerdo
  70%  { top: 1910px; left: 100%; transform: translate(-120%, -120%) } //vai para a direita
  75%  { top: 1915px; left: 100%; transform: translate(-120%, -50%) } //desce do lado direito
  85%  { top: 1915px; left: 0px; transform: translate(35%, -50%) } //vai para a esquerda
  90%  { top: 2320px; left: 0px; transform: translate(35%, -120%) } //desce do lado esquerdo
  100% { top: 2320px; left: 100%; transform: translate(-120%, -120%) } //vai para a direita
}
```

Eu queria usar aquele código (ou um que faça o mesmo) para inverter a imagem depois do código que diz que "desce do lado direito" após os 15%.

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido.

É apenas necessário adicionar `scaleX(-1)` após `translate`.